# Netflix-desktop no longer works after update

Tags: wine

So a while ago I installed netflix-desktop on my ubuntu 12.10 installation. I am also a subscriber to redbox instant. I attempted to install redbox-desktop which is from the same ppa as the netflix-desktop.

Here is the link to the story about this
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/01/how-to-watch-lovefilm-redbox-instant-or-netflix-on-ubuntu

The only problem is that when I attempted to install it it updated netflix-desktop in the process. Now when I click on netflix-desktop I wait and nothing happens. Redbox-desktop no longer works either. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling with the same result. Please help I need me my Doctor Who!

EDIT: I also noticed that when I reinstalled netflix the silverlight and mozilla firefox (the one ran through wine) have disappeared. I am not sure if that is relevant

Comment: This sounds like a bug, you should report bugs at  Launchpad not here.

Comment: I have a problem. I am asking if anyone has experienced this problem and if they know how to fix it. This seems like the perfect place

Comment: Yes, but understand that Ask Ubuntu is not a bug-tracker bug issues are strictly **off-topic**, if a user happens to know the solution you'll get an answer if not you *should* report your bug at the Launchpad page of the developer not *here*.

Comment: Try starting from the terminal `netflix-desktop` this may show any errors. Paste the results into your question. Also how did you uninstall as it may be better to purge the ppa and all its related software before trying again `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:ehoover/compholio`

Comment: I have already done all of what you suggested. Sorry for not including it. no errors were shown and I purged the ppa and then added it again. THanks though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new version of Netflix Desktop moves the profile location from `~/.netflix-desktop` to `~/.wine-browser`.  You might try renaming/deleting the `~/.wine-browser` folder and relaunching `netflix-desktop` (or `redbox-desktop`) so that it creates a new profile.

Comment: It is a shame you did not comment a little I had a bounty and you would be 50 reputation points richer. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Try `rm -Rf ~/.wine-browser` in terminal, then restart netflix after that.