# Error starting netflix-desktop Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: software-installation, netflix

Hi I'm trying to use the Netflix Desktop application on my Ubuntu 13.04 machine. After following [these instructions](http://www.howtogeek.com/130372/how-to-watch-netflix-on-ubuntu-with-the-netflix-desktop-app/) I've run into a couple of errors. Attempting to open the application through the HUD gives me

```
Unable to test extended attributes at location '/home/username/.wine-browser'.
```

Trying to open it through the command line gives me a bit of a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/wine-browser-installer/test-xattr", line 3, in <module>
    import xattr
ImportError: No module named xattr
```

I've gone through and attempted to install the xattr python module: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xattr

But, running

```
python setup.py install
```

gives me a long list of errors involving gcc...

I've also found this, but deleting/renaming .wine-browser didn't work - I [followed this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249560/netflix-desktop-no-longer-works-after-update).

Does anybody have any idea how to fix this issue? Having Netflix for Ubuntu would be a major plus for me! Thanks!

Comment: I've figured something out that some people may find useful. The standard version of python which ships with Ubuntu has the module xattr, though I use Anaconda python. There are two options I can see working: 1) Tell netflix-desktop which version of python to use, or 2) Try to get xattr for Anaconda python. I'm going to try option number two first.

Comment: This will allow the installation of xattr with Anaconda python: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/NJNckra1JBA.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and, in my case, it happened because `root` was the owner of `.wine-browser` directory:

```
$ ls -lhd /home/username/.wine-browser/
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4,0K Jul  4 23:08 /home/username/.wine-browser/
```

I solved the problem by opening a terminal as `root` and change the user/group of Wine directory:

```
$ sudo su
# cd /home/username
# chown -R username.usergroup .wine-browser/`
```

> where `username.usergroup` is your user "login/group".

After that, I opened the netflix-desktop and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the post. One question? What is my 'group' if the computer is only used by me and I have root access?

Comment: Use `groups username` to view the groups the user is part of. Pick the first one for the commands above.

Comment: Hmm. This didn't seem to work for me. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, notice that the `test-xattr` file has `#!/usr/bin/env python` on its first line, which means the system is getting the default python setup on your environment. In my case, the `xattr` module was installed on my 2.7 python, and the default was 3.x.

So all I did was change the first line to `#!/usr/bin/python2.7`.

Answer (score 1):

What I did sure isn't the right answer but it works,
I comment all the lines in the file `/usr/share/wine-browser-installer/test-xattr` and I put only a `print hello`. It shows a error when installing but after that Netflix starts working..

I hope it helps you.